# How to Fix “Command Not Found” in command line

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh

Chances are that you might be getting the following error on your Mac, when you have been trying to run commands in the terminal
and you have already installed the commands

```
zsh: command not found: git
```

or

```
zsh: command not found: curl
```

The fix is in the answer below

Comment: You install the command and make sure it's in your PATH

Answer (score 4):

Chances are that something might have gone wrong with the users $PATH on your machine or maybe the actual path where the command is has not been set.

You can just run the command below, this should fix you issue:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
```

and if you feel like checking the path you can just run :

```
echo $PATH
```